# Learning Data Science

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have just now started with learning data scince and just now have started with pandas.
For the below code I am getting error:

```
from pandas_datareader import data
df= data.read_csv('C:\\Users\\n.bv.sharma\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\miniconda3\\envs\\myEnv\\pkgs\\datasets\\nyv_weather.csv')
df


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-cba7d10c8f67> in <module>
      1 from pandas_datareader import data
----> 2 df= data.read_csv('C:\\Users\\n.bv.sharma\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\miniconda3\\envs\\myEnv\\pkgs\\datasets\\nyv_weather.csv')
      3 df

AttributeError: module 'pandas_datareader.data' has no attribute 'read_csv'


----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Please help me out with the solution

Comment: You should do: df = pd.read_csv(filepath)

Comment: to add to @Arkadiusz - `import pandas as pd` and then `df = pd.read_csv(filepath)`. you will find this in any pandas tutorial... please see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/tutorials.html

Answer (score 1):

i think the problem is related to you import:
you should import the pandas module

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv(file)
```

why are using pandas_datareader.data?